# Is it possible to capture KeyDown-events and to cancel this Event afterwards in C#?

Tags: c#, winapi, keyboard-events

I want to translate the Latin keyboard to another Keyboard like uyghur or something like.  There is an uyghur keyboard, but the coding of keys are so complex that a normal PC User can't type uighur easily.

So my aim is that to create a software solution for this Problem, such as Chinese Input Systems. in that system you can input Chinese Characters from every kind of Keyboard. that is a kind of clever solution so that everyone can use it problem-less.

So my aim is that I want to write a Windows Service Application, which captures every KeyDown-Strike (only Alphabets) and translates the pressed Key to destination (Unicode) Alphabet and simulates again a Key strike with this translated Alphabet. As result the aimed Alphabet will be showed in the cursor-point. In the End my App discards/Stops the original key from the KEYDOWN pressing,

So that it will not be showed any more.

For example:

1. Press <kbd>K</kbd>.
2. Capturing the <kbd>K</kbd> and Translate it to Unicode like `0xFEBD` then send back to cursor point.
3. Cancel or Discard the key down event of the <kbd>K</kbd>. This character should not be seen at the cursor point.

Until now the Step 1 and 2 works fine. My problem is that I can't discard/cancel/stop the last key down event for this key strike, after I capture the key down event.

I am not sure if my idea good/effective enough to realize what I am thinking. Now I am trying only. may be you have a better idea that you can suggest me. here is my code for that:

```
public class Simulate
{
    [DllImport("USER32.DLL", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    static extern UInt32 SendInput(UInt32 numberOfInputs, INPUT[] input, Int32 sizeOfInputStructure);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Size = 24)]
    struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public UInt16 Vk;
        public UInt16 Scan;
        public UInt32 Flags;
        public UInt32 Time;
        public UInt32 ExtraInfo;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    private struct INPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public int Type;
        [FieldOffset(4)]
        public KEYBDINPUT ki;
    }
    public static void UnicodeInput(UInt16 unicode)
    { 
            INPUT down = new INPUT();
            down.Type = 1; //INPUT_KEYBOARD
            down.ki.Vk = 0;
            down.ki.Scan = unicode;
            down.ki.Time = 0;
            down.ki.Flags = 0x0004; //KEYEVENTF_UNICODE
            down.ki.ExtraInfo = 0;

            INPUT up = new INPUT();
            up.Type = 1; //INPUT_KEYBOARD
            up.ki.Vk = 0;
            up.ki.Scan = unicode;
            up.ki.Time = 0;
            up.ki.Flags = 0x0004; //KEYEVENTF_UNICODE
            up.ki.ExtraInfo = 0;

            INPUT[] input = new INPUT[2];
            input[0] = down;
            input[1] = up;
            SendInput(1, input, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT))); 
    }

}    

/// Capture any window key
/// 
public static class WinKeyCapture
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WH_CALLWNDPROC = 4;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int WM_CHAR = 0x0102;
    const int VK_A = 0x08;// 0x41; //up key
    const int VK_DOWN = 0x28;  //down key
    const int VK_LEFT = 0x25;
    const int VK_RIGHT = 0x27;
    const uint KEYEVENTF_KEYUP = 0x0002;
    const uint KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY = 0x0001;

    const uint KEYEVENTF_CTRL = 0x11;
    const uint KEYEVENTF_ADD = 0x6B;
    const uint VK_LWIN = 0x5b;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = WinKeyCapture.HookCallback; 
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern void keybd_event(byte bVk, byte bScan, uint dwFlags, uint dwExtraInfo);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern uint SendInput(uint numberOfInputs, INPUT[] inputs, int sizeOfInputStructure);

    public static void SetHook()
    {

        SetHook(_proc);
    }

    public static void UnHook()
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        { 
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0); 
        }
    }
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;       

    public static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam); 

        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN) 
        {         
            // TODO: identify only Alphabets then fire     
           VKcode(vkCode);                  
        }
        //wParam |=   0x4000;
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private static void VKcode(int code)
    { 
        switch (code) // TODO: Complete all other Alphabet-Tranylations
        {  
            case 0x4B:
                 Simulate.UnicodeInput(0xFEDB);
                break;  
            case 0x54:
                  Simulate.UnicodeInput(0xFEAD);
                break;
            case 0x55:
                 Simulate.UnicodeInput(0xFBE7);
                break;
            case 0x56:    
                 Simulate.UnicodeInput(0xFEE9); 

                break;
            case 0x59:
                Simulate.UnicodeInput(0xFEE1);
                break;
            case 0x5a: 
                break; 
        }  
    }        


    /// <summary>
    /// simulate key press
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keyCode"></param>
    public static void SendKeyPress(KeyCode keyCode)
    {
        INPUT input = new INPUT {
            Type = 1
        };
        input.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT() {
            Vk = (ushort)keyCode,
            Scan = 0,
            Flags = 0,
            Time = 0,
            ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero,
        };

        INPUT input2 = new INPUT {
            Type = 1
        };
        input2.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT() {
            Vk = (ushort)keyCode,
            Scan = 0,
            Flags = 2,
            Time = 0,
            ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero
        };
        INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[] { input, input2 };
        if (SendInput(2, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT))) == 0)
            throw new Exception();            
    } 
        /// <summary>
    /// simulate key press
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="keyCode"></param>
    public static void SendUnicodePress(KeyCode keyCode)
    {
        INPUT input = new INPUT {
            Type = 1
        };
        input.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT() {
            Vk = (ushort)keyCode,
            Scan = 0,
            Flags = 0,
            Time = 0,
            ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero,
        };

        INPUT input2 = new INPUT {
            Type = 1
        };
        input2.Data.Keyboard = new KEYBDINPUT() {
            Vk = (ushort)keyCode,
            Scan = 0,
            Flags = 2,
            Time = 0,
            ExtraInfo = IntPtr.Zero
        };
        INPUT[] inputs = new INPUT[] { input, input2 };
        if (SendInput(2, inputs, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(INPUT))) == 0)
            throw new Exception();            
    } 
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct INPUT
    {
        public uint Type;
        public MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT Data;
    } 
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
    internal struct MOUSEKEYBDHARDWAREINPUT
    {
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public HARDWAREINPUT Hardware;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public KEYBDINPUT Keyboard;
        [FieldOffset(0)]
        public MOUSEINPUT Mouse;
    }
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct HARDWAREINPUT
    {
        public uint Msg;
        public ushort ParamL;
        public ushort ParamH;
    } 
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct KEYBDINPUT
    {
        public ushort Vk;
        public ushort Scan;
        public uint Flags;
        public uint Time;
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    } 
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    internal struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int X;
        public int Y;
        public uint MouseData;
        public uint Flags;
        public uint Time;
        public IntPtr ExtraInfo;
    }
}
```

Comment: Creating an IME requires using the Text Services Framework.  A large set of COM interfaces for which there is no type library available, which makes it *very* difficult to use from a C# app.  IMEs are written in C++, get started on one with [this sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Input-Method-Editor-IME-b1610980).  Do note that Uyghur is already supported by Windows and readily selectable from the language bar after adding the language with Control Panel + Language.

Comment: @HansPassant i know that the Uighur is already supported by Windows. but the Uighur Keyboard is so complex to use or  to type because of the Distribution or Coding of Alphabets in Latin Keyboard. you should always change with Shif-Key to type some Other Uighurkeys. so i want to try to realize a software solution if possible.